# Remover aspas do Resultado Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-eloquent

Estou recebendo um resultado via `Request` no `Laravel` dessa forma: "2,1", preciso remover as aspas duplas do resultado, pois quando insiro como parâmetro na consulta o `whereIn` entende como uma `string` ao invés de um `array` e retorna apenas 1 resultado ao invés de todos.

Comment: poste o código completo !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se vier um texto que os elementos são separados por virgula, utilize [explode](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.explode.php) para criar um `array` de cada elemento e depois se precisa de um `array` de inteiros utilize [array_map](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-map.php) que vai aplicar a função [intval](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.intval.php) em cada elemento do `array`:

***Código***

```
<?php

    $str = "2,1";

    $str = array_map(function($value){
        return intval($value);
    }, explode(",", $str));
```

***Saída:***

```
array(2) { [0]=> int(2) [1]=> int(1) }
```

para [verificar o resultado ONLINE](https://ideone.com/tgdE95).

<sub>***Referencias***</sub>

- [explode](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.explode.php)
- [array_map](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-map.php)
- [intval](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.intval.php)

Answer (score 0):

Use a função [explode](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.explode.php) do PHP:

```
$string = "2,1";
$array = explode(",", $string);
```

o resultado será:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 1
)
```

Comment: Obrigado a todos o explode funcionou muito obrigado!!!